# error when try to install selenium or any app in python

Tags: python

I just start programming in Python and installed the 3.5 v 32bits but when I try the command `pip install selenium` this error message appears :

`Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:07:06) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information`

```
>>> dir C:\py*
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    dir C:\py*
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> pip install selenium
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install selenium
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> pip install cx_Freeze
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install cx_Freeze
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Any command I try there is the same error
Environment variable path : C:\Python35-32\Scripts\
windows path : C:\Python35-32

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid Python code. It may work as an extension in IPython, but please read some Python tutorials first.